# WPF what is the default template for WPF Extended ToolKit's ColorPicker?

Tags: wpf, xaml, color-picker

I just want to be able to the color of the region with the arrow on the right without disturbing the left box that is bound to the selected color.

http://postimg.org/image/smp369kpd/

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you were googling a bit. So if you cannot find a standard template, you could still [download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24036) a trial version of MS Expression Blend and extract the template.

It's been a while, since I used it. But the last time the trial lasts for 60 days.

Comment: didn't realize there was extraction capability in blend..sounds useful

Answer (score 0):

This is an open-source library, so you can go to the source on CodePlex: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution_35/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/ColorPicker/Themes/Generic.xaml